# What is mean by setRequestedFps in CameraSource Google Mobile vision API

Tags: android, google-api

What is the meaning of setRequestedFps in mobile vision API.

Camera Code :

```
mCameraSource =
            new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), textRecognizer)
                    .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                    .setRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 1024)
                    .setRequestedFps(40.0f)

                    .setFlashMode(useFlash ? Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH : null)
                    .setFocusMode(autoFocus ? Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE : null)
                    .build();
```

Initializing Processing Object.

```
ocrDetectorProcessor  =new OcrDetectorProcessor(this,mGraphicOverlay,documentType);
    TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(context).build();
    textRecognizer.setProcessor(ocrDetectorProcessor);
```

Processor Class

```
class OcrDetectorProcessor{
public OcrDetectorProcessor(OcrCaptureActivity ocrCaptureActivity,GraphicOverlay<OcrGraphic> mGraphicOverlay,String documentType) {

}
@Override
public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {

}}
```

**My Question :
If I set setRequestedFps(40.0f) then receiveDetections will called 40 times in a second or not**

Answer (score 3):

Yes if The device supports.
If not it will change to the best available FPS.

as it mentioned at [Google APIs for Android](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/CameraSource.Builder.html#setRequestedFps(float))

> Sets the requested frame rate in frames per second. If the exact requested value is not available, the best matching available value is selected. Default: 30.

Comment: I read this. but my question is If I set setRequestedFps(40.0f) then receiveDetections will called 40 times in a second or not

Answer (score 3):

> My Question : If I set setRequestedFps(40.0f) then receiveDetections
>   will (be) called 40 times in a second or not

Camera will send that many frames to the underlying detector. Now whether or not the detector is able to process that many frames in a second will depend on the processing power of your phone